# Google Drive Sync and Ransomware

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a PC connected to the network in my small company, and the folder related to important data are synchronized via Google Drive Sync, if unfortunately a ransomware or other virus should encrypt or damage the data, Google Drive would synchronize the new corrupt data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all synchronizers spread the infection. If you want to have the files safe from viruses, look for a solution in the cloud that does not have the files locally. Thus a hypothetical virus could not reach them. Take a look to Dataprius, Sharepoint or Documentum.